# How do I check DNS resolving and propagation for custom domain on AWS

Tags: amazon-route53

I have a site hosted on Heroku using custom domains hosted on AWS Route 53.  I contacted Heroku support who reviewed my DNS settings on AWS and confirmed the configuration is correct but requests to the DNS service are still failing.  They provided the following info in their response:

```
To resolve the issue, I recommend checking the DNS resolving and propagation for the custom domains with your DNS provider, which in this case is Amazon.
```

I'm on the basic plan and do not have technical support with Amazon.  I have set up a CNAME record that points to the Heroku DNS endpoint along with an A Type record that points to the naked domain hosted in an S3 bucket that points back to the www CNAME record in route 53.  What do I need to do to set up the DNS resolving and propagation for the custom domain on AWS?